# how to render the below static html and css in reactjs

Tags: html, css, reactjs

```
<h3 style="text-align:start;"><span style="color: rgb(97,189,109);font-size: 24px;font-family: Source Sans Pro;">(optional) customChunkRenderer</span></h3>
<p><span style="color: rgb(51,51,51);font-size: 18px;font-family: Source Sans Pro;">Use to define additional HTML nodes. Only supports atomic blocks.</span></p>
```

the above code has to be sanitized in react, like

[image]

Comment: [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example of your attempt to render the raw html?

Comment: Assuming you're using JSX, the only part that needs changing here is to format your inline styles into style objects. Have you made an attempt at this yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use jsx and convert this to jsx format

use this -

```
<h3 style={{textAlign: 'start'}}><span style={{color: 'rgb(97,189,109)', fontSize: 24, fontFamily: 'Source Sans Pro'}}>(optional) customChunkRenderer</span></h3>
<p><span style={{color: 'rgb(51,51,51)', fontSize: 18, fontFamily: 'Source Sans Pro'}}>Use to define additional HTML nodes. Only supports atomic blocks.</span></p>
```